# DaVinci Error code 999 , the gpu failed to perform image processing error code 999

Tags: error-code, video-editing, davinci, davinci-resolve

I recently installed DaVinci resolve 18.1 and got "the gpu failed to perform image processing error code 999" Error as soon as I started the Program. I had no Clue . Requires  solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to fix Error code 999 (the gpu failed to perform image processing).

1. Get the latest Driver for your gpu
2. Switch to NVIDIA Performance mode in NVIDIA x Server Prime Profile

```
 NVIDIA x Server -> Prime Profile -> NVIDIA (Performance mode)
```

3. Reboot

Comment: Hi, I don't have any Prime Profile in my NVIDIA x Server. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a prime profile in the NVidia X server settings like me, acquire the nvidia-prime package and run a 'prime-run' prefix on the executable in terminal. Fixed it for me.

prime-run /opt/resolve/bin/resolve

Answer (score 0):

This **prime-run /opt/resolve/bin/resolve** showed "prime-run: command not found". I did were these steps:

1. Copy the contents of the gist: [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/abenson/a5264836c4e6bf22c8c8415bb616204a)

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> export __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
> export __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
> export __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only
> export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
> exec "$@"
> ```

2. Create a file **`~/bin/prime-run`** ("~" means your home directory)
3. Run **`chmod +x "~/bin/prime-run"`** to make it executable.
4. Closed and re-opened my terminal. After this, it worked by running: **`prime-run /opt/resolve/bin/resolve`**

I am using Fedora 37.

Source: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364762/prime-run-command-not-found).

Answer (score 0):

On my machine I was finally able to fix it by prepending

`env __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia`

when executing the resolve binary.

Since I run wayland It's tricky to launch gui programs from the terminal so I  added this to the `Exec` line in the .desktop entry at `/usr/share/applications/DaVinciResolve.desktop` (on Arch, yours may be somewhere else) so the final command that runs looks like:

`env __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia /opt/resolve/bin/resolve %u`